# JOIN two tables and print product name and price which category id is 77

Tags: sql

I have two tables and I want to join them using SQL queries and display the product on product page

Table 1 [table name: A] has `product_id` and `category_id` whereas, table 2 [table name: B] has `product_id`, `product_name` and `price`.

Here, I want to join Table A and B and SELECT all products from table B which `category_id` = 77 in table A.

I want to print `product_name`, and `price` on product page which has only 77 category id.

Comment: This is a pure sql question. You can remove the tags php and html or extend your question.

Comment: SELECT product_name, price FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.product_id = B.product_id WHERE A.category_id = 77;

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    B.product_name,
    B.price
FROM
    B
    JOIN A ON A.product_id = B.product_id
WHERE
    A.category_id = 77
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT 
   B.product_name,
   B.price
 FROM A,B
 WHERE 
    A.product_id = B.product_id
    AND A.category_id = 77;
```

is also possible. (tried on MySQL and Oracle DB)